# Sysprep Win10 - Custom profile pic and modifying Default Profile taskbar icons

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-profiles, sysprep

I'm looking at the unattend.xml file provided by my supervisor and am trying to find a place to put in a file path to a custom profile picture for a specific user (NOT the Default Profile). I couldn't find solutions on Google. I was also taking a look at [Microsoft's sample unattend file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732280(v=ws.10).aspx) to see if there was a place for it, but didn't see one. This is all the options I found for creating/customizing a local account (from Microsoft's sample unattend file):

```
               <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount>
                          <Password>
                                <Value>Password1</Value>
                                <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                          </Password>
                          <Description>My Local Account</Description>
                          <DisplayName>John Smith</DisplayName>
                          <Group>Administrators;Power Users</Group>
                          <Name>John</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
              </LocalAccounts>
```

Also, I'd like to customize the taskbar icons for the Default Profile. [On step 4.2 of this guide](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3020-customize-windows-10-image-audit-mode-sysprep.html), it says that going into Audit mode to customize the Default Profile in Windows 10 will not allow you to change the taskbar icons. I know a previous employee customized these somehow, but it very well could have been through something other than Sysprep. Any ideas on how to do this?

...I do also want to customize the profile picture of the Default Profile, but I think that will be carried over if I make the change in Audit mode, correct?